# Rails – order by "important", where "important" is in another table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a list of posts, which user can mark as "Important". When he listing them I want important ones to be the first, and all others should be below.
User mark post as important using another model, ImportantPost, which belongs to User and belongs to Post. The problem is I don't know how can I re-order Posts with conditions in "order" statement – every user have his own list of "important" posts.

My models are:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :important_posts
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :important_posts
end

class ImportantPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

I wrote code just right in here, because my real situation is a little bit harder.
The best I came with so far is:

```
Post.joins(:important_posts).select("post.*, important_posts.user_id = #{current_user.id} as important").order('important')
```

The only thing – it displays only posts which have been marked as important. For example, if totally there's a 3 posts, but only one marked as "Important" – the code above will return only one post.

**UPD**

Looks like join with left outer JOIN solve my problem... can it cause any problems?.. Should I use full outer join?

Comment: Can you post your schema up please?  Just the User, Post and ImportantPost classes and their relationships with each other (not the whole classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, my problem fully solved by using `outer left join`. It's a first time I use `outer join` and it's good!